# Mount of shared windows drive in /etc/fstab failing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, cifs

I’m having problems mounting /mnt/data on my newest vmware VM.  I’m not sure what next to try next to get /mnt/data to show me my shared folder – I’m doing it through /etc/fstab in Ubuntu. So I thought I’d ask for ideas on anything I might’ve overlooked.

VM IP address is 192.168.136.143,
Ubuntu Version 18.04
Windows Laptop [216TN533]
IP: (Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL)) 172.19.64.1

(Wireless LAN Adapter Wi-Fi)             192.168.1.6

(Additional detailed version information at end of this message)

In /etc/fstab started with (password elided in this message as ********):

//216TN533/UbuntuShare /mnt/data cifs username=kafkaetl,password=********,uid=nobody,iocharset=utf8,noperm 0 0

sudo mount -av

returns:

mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=172.19.64.1,unc=\216TN53\UbuntuShare,iocharset=utf8,noperm,uid=65534,user=kafkaetl,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

From the mount man page about the above error:

If you get the error "mount error(13) permission denied", then the server denied your access. Here are the first things to check:

•   Are you using a valid username and password? Does that account really have access to this folder?.

o   I can login as kafkaetl so I believe that is correct

•   Do you have whitespace in your credentials file? It should be password=mspassword, not password = mspassword.

o   No whitespace

•   Is the security setting correct? The most common is sec=ntlm, but you can also try the other options listed at the mount.cifs man page. The man page list leaves out the option sec=lanman for some reason, but you should try that one as well (see discussion).

o   Added sec=ntlm

•   Do you need a domain? For example, if you are told that your username is SALES\sally, then actually your username is sally and your domain is SALES. The fstab entry should read:
...username=sally,password=pass,domain=SALES,... Or:
...credentials=/path/to/file,domain=SALES,...

o   Added domain=216TN53

•   cifs-utils and nfs-common are installed.

•   Nothing has been changed on the share on the windows side

Then setting security (sec=ntlm) option in fstab:

```
//216TN533/UbuntuShare /mnt/data cifs username=kafkaetl,password=********,uid=nobody,iocharset=utf8,noperm,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

results in:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=172.19.64.1,unc=\\216TN53\UbuntuShare,iocharset=utf8,noperm,sec=ntlm,uid=65534,user=kafkaetl,pass=********

mount error(2): No such file or directory
```

From dmesg the concurrently logged message is:

(Screenshot)

As I investigated, I noticed that on 2 sequential ip addr requests, the V4 IP address reported had changed (w.x.y.145 to w.x.y.146) The only activity between the two invocations was the login screen had appeared.

I checked the firewall, and a `sudo ufw status` returns inactive.

Any additional ideas on why I can’t see the contents of UbuntuShare as /mnt/data? I see the changing IP address as shown above as a problem, which I don’t have the root cause for.

Additional detailed version information:

Ubuntu Version Information:

ubuntu@ubuntu1804:~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Release:        18.04

Codename:       bionic

cifs-utils is already the newest version (2:6.8-1ubuntu1.1).

ubuntu@ubuntu1804:~$ modinfo cifs
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-113-generic/kernel/fs/cifs/cifs.ko
softdep:        pre: gcm
softdep:        pre: ccm
softdep:        pre: aead2
softdep:        pre: sha512
softdep:        pre: sha256
softdep:        pre: cmac
softdep:        pre: aes
softdep:        pre: nls
softdep:        pre: md5
softdep:        pre: md4
softdep:        pre: hmac
softdep:        pre: ecb
version:        2.23
description:    VFS to access SMB3 servers e.g. Samba, Macs, Azure and Windows (and also older servers complying with the SNIA CIFS Specification)
license:        GPL
author:         Steve French
alias:          smb3
alias:          fs-smb3
alias:          fs-cifs
srcversion:     BD97FCA7658860567230815
depends:        fscache,libdes,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cifs
vermagic:       5.4.0-113-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           CIFSMaxBufSize:Network buffer size (not including header) for CIFS requests. Default: 16384 Range: 8192 to 130048 (uint)
parm:           cifs_min_rcv:Network buffers in pool. Default: 4 Range: 1 to 64 (uint)
parm:           cifs_min_small:Small network buffers in pool. Default: 30 Range: 2 to 256 (uint)
parm:           cifs_max_pending:Simultaneous requests to server for CIFS/SMB1 dialect (N/A for SMB3) Default: 32767 Range: 2 to 32767. (uint)
parm:           enable_oplocks:Enable or disable oplocks. Default: y/Y/1 (bool)
parm:           enable_gcm_256:Enable requesting strongest (256 bit) GCM encryption. Default: n/N/0 (bool)
parm:           require_gcm_256:Require strongest (256 bit) GCM encryption. Default: n/N/0 (bool)
parm:           disable_legacy_dialects:To improve security it may be helpful to restrict the ability to override the default dialects (SMB2.1, SMB3 and SMB3.02) on mount with old dialects (CIFS/SMB1 and SMB2) since vers=1.0 (CIFS/SMB1) and vers=2.0 are weaker and less secure. Default: n/N/0 (bool)

references:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man8/mount.cifs.8.html

Comment: I installed Samba on my Ubuntu Linux guest (Windows 11 Host VMware) and configured Samba.  Then in Windows Explorer \\192.168.x.y where this is the IP of the Linux Machine
. That works here.